# Java 20 @PostConstruct does not exist. How?

Tags: java, postconstruct

In Java 20 (oracle's openjdk 20), I don't see the `@PostConstruct`.

What must I do/import so that I can have an annotation to do perform the same thing?

Using Spring 6.0.10.

Comment: See the note near the bottom of the page: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/annotation-config/postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations.html